# major and minor macros defined in sys/sysmacros.h pulled in by <iterator>

Tags: c++, macros, glibc, libstdc++

I'm writing a class that has a matrix-like structure and I want to have a member function named minor to be the same as the matrix operation. This triggers some errors. A minimal test case on my system:

```
#include <iterator>
void minor(int row, int col);
```

When compiled, clang provides the following error:

```
$ clang++ -Weverything -std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp:2:21: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
void minor(int row, int col);
                    ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysmacros.h:67:10: note: macro 'minor' defined here
# define minor(dev) gnu_dev_minor (dev)
         ^
test.cpp:2:6: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void minor(int row, int col);
     ^
2 errors generated.
$
```

The relevant portion of sys/sysmacros.h is:

```
/* Access the functions with their traditional names.  */
# define major(dev) gnu_dev_major (dev)
# define minor(dev) gnu_dev_minor (dev)
# define makedev(maj, min) gnu_dev_makedev (maj, min)
```

Clearly, these specific macros could be #undef'd, but it seems quite silly that such routine words as major and minor would be defined as macros, particularly when pulling in part of the C++ standard library. Is there some reason these need to be defined? Is this a bug in the standard library I'm using? (libstdc++ 4.8.2 as in Debian testing)

Comment: Try `-std=c++11 -ansi`

Comment: Adding -ansi gets that minimal testcase to work, but it triggers errors elsewhere in my project, so I can't enable it, at least in the short term. Are there any options other than -ansi?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the C++ standard those names shouldn't be reserved to the implementation and thus be available.

According to `man 3 makedev`:

> The makedev(), major(), and minor() functions are not specified in
> POSIX.1, but are present on many other systems

and

> These  interfaces  are defined as macros.  Since glibc 2.3.3, they
> have been  aliases  for  three  GNU-specific  functions:
> gnu_dev_makedev(), gnu_dev_major(),  and gnu_dev_minor().  The latter
> names are exported, but the traditional names are more portable.

It seems that they aren't removed for backward compatibility (e.g. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=130601).

I think you could `#undef` them without major issues (many projects proceed in this way).

With [G++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html)/CLANG/[MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/push-macro) you could also do something like:

```
#pragma push_macro("minor")
#undef minor

// do what you need

#pragma pop_macro("minor")
```

It's ugly, but helps with naming conflicts.

Moreover, depending on how your code is structured, this trick can be useful:

```
#define minor(dev) gnu_dev_major(dev)

void (minor)(int row, int col) { /* ... */ }
```

In the function definition line, the character after 'minor' is a close parenthesis, so it is not a macro invocation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Redhat bug. I have filed a bug with gcc since the -std=c++11 should have not pulled in these macros. Jonathan Wakely marked my filing as a dupe of http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51749 with the note that fixing this problem is general was on his list after the 4.9 release.