# C++11 member initialization list ambiguity

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I am struggling with what appears to be an ambiguity in c++11 symbol resolution due to the GNU standard library implementation in this environment:

- Arch Linux 4.2.5-1 (x86_64)
- g++ 5.2.0
- clang++ 3.7.0

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct version {

  unsigned major;
  unsigned minor;
  unsigned patch;

  version(unsigned major, unsigned minor, unsigned patch) :
    major(major), minor(minor), patch(patch) { }

  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, version const& v) {
    out << v.major << ".";
    out << v.minor << ".";
    out << v.patch;
    return out;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  version v(1, 1, 0);
  std::cout << v << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error: member initializer 'gnu_dev_major' does not name a non-static data
  member or base class
error: member initializer 'gnu_dev_minor' does not name a non-static data
  member or base class
```

Command:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -o test *.cpp
```

The scope resolution operator does not appear to be applicable in member initialization lists so I can't figure out how to resolve the ambiguity. This sample compiles fine without the c++11 flag.

Comment: It also compiles fine with MSVC 2015

Comment: The same problem found here [major and minor macros defined in sys/sysmacros.h pulled in by <iterator>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240973/major-and-minor-macros-defined-in-sys-sysmacros-h-pulled-in-by-iterator)

Comment: @Myria they are macros defined by gcc

Comment: **great** Now I have to add gnu to the list of compilers that add stupid stupid macro definitions. First being of course  Visual Studio with `min` and `max`, and everything like `#define CreateFile CreateFileW` which is pretty much everything.

Comment: Filed a glibc bug report, it is linked in my answer below.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Another way is to use braces:

```
version(unsigned major, unsigned minor, unsigned patch) :
  major{major}, minor{minor}, patch{patch} { }
```

Then the macros will not interfere because they are function-like macros and need parentheses to be invoked.

Comment: great answer! better solution than undefining macros

Comment: @ChrisHutchinson *"better solution than undefining"* I don't know about that; They should not be there in the first place as they are not implementation reserved identifiers. I like `#undef`ing them. (Upvoted this too, as it is a valid and clean solution for people who want to use those macros.)

Comment: Interesting--that's an [unexpected benefit of brace-initialization.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33444814/1858225)

Comment: @BaummitAugen `#undef`ing them means now you're specifically designing your code around non-standard definitions that "should not be there"; that's about as inelegant as you can get.

Comment: @Leushenko it's my experience, and the stories I've heard confirm it, that if you want your code to be portable in practice, you need to work around the odd little differences in various implementations, and that's simply never going to be elegant. These `#undef`s should be in a header used throughout your project for portability. Note, too, that this technique allows *initializing* these members, but it doesn't really probably any protection against macro substitution in other syntactic contexts.

Answer (score 19):

From my own compilation attempt, it looks like glibc is doing something stupid and `#define`ing common lowercase words.

When I add the following after the `#include`s, it compiles.

```
#undef major
#undef minor
```

Answer (score 15):

It looks like `major` and `minor` are macros defined in `sys/sysmacros.h` which is being brought in by `<iostream>`, which is problematic since these names [are not reserved for the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/1708801). Note if the code is reduced and we solely include `sys/sysmacros.h` directly the same problem will occur.

When I compile this with [clang on Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/A9iGmJ0bfcLt2tIT) I get this more informative error which allows us to see where the conflict is coming from:

```
 usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysmacros.h:67:21: note: expanded from macro 'major'
 # define major(dev) gnu_dev_major (dev)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysmacros.h:68:21: note: expanded from macro 'minor'
 # define minor(dev) gnu_dev_minor (dev)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

We can find this documented in the following bug report [identifier major macro expanded into gnu_dev_major](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=130601):

> The problem is that g++ adds -D_GNU_SOURCE and major() is a macro
>   in _GNU_SOURCE (or _BSD_SOURCE or when no feature set is requested).
>
> You can always #undef major after including headers.

and:

> makedev(), major() and minor() should be functions, not macros.
>
> It looks they were introduced in **GNUC** >= 2 in sys/sysmacros.h for 
>   backward compatibility.
>   It is not a good idea.
>
> Fiddling with macros is dangerous since it pollutes user name space.

and so we can see `undef` the macros is one solution and it is unfortunately the recommended solution since this is  a won't fix bug:

> There will be no change.  If some code does not like the macros, add
>   #undefs after the appropriate #include.  The macros are part of the
>   API and removing them only causes problems.

We could use `{}` in the member intializer but this requires changes the types of the parameters since leaving them as *int* would be a narrowing conversion which is not allowed. Of course changing names is also a possible solution.

**Update**

I filed a [glibc bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19239). There is some questions about whether this is really a gcc or a glibc bug, the details are rather involved.

Comment: If it doesn't already exist I would file a new bug report against glibc. This is a result of nasty interaction of multiple header files: `_GNU_SOURCE` causes `stdlib.h` to include `sys/types.h`, and it causes `sys/types.h` to include `sys/sysmacros.h`. The cascading of these two behaviors is completely unintentional and unwanted.

Comment: I concur with R..: file a new bug report (in the upstream bugzilla, not Red Hat's: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/) The glibc maintainers' attitudes toward this sort of thing have changed considerably since 2004.

Comment: @R.. filed a bug report and it is linked in my answer

Comment: I'm pleased to report that glibc has decided to remove these macros from `sys/types.h` in a future release.  There's no exact schedule yet, though.

Answer (score 9):

/usr/include/sys/sysmacros.h has following macros defined:

```
# define major(dev) gnu_dev_major (dev)
# define minor(dev) gnu_dev_minor (dev)
# define makedev(maj, min) gnu_dev_makedev (maj, min)
```

looks like you have to undef them or use other names